# Regex Expression to remove "autoplay" parameter in url

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I'm trying to match the url `https://youtube.com/embed/id` and its parameters i.e `?start=10&autoplay=1`, but I need the autoplay parameter removed or set to 0.

These are some example urls and what I want the results to look like:

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1`

I want to remove the autoplay parameter and its value:

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY`

2nd example

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?start=10&autoplay=1`

results should be

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?start=10`

I have tried `(https?:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]+)(\?[^\t\n\f\r \"']*)(\bautoplay=[01]\b&?)` and replace with `$1$2`, but it matches with a trailing `?` and `&` in example 1 and 2 respectively. Also, it doesn't match at all for a url like
`http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY`

I have the regex and examples on [here](https://regex101.com/r/iI1BRO/6)

NB:
The string I am working on contains HTML with one or more youtube urls in it, so I don't think I can easily use go's net/url package to parse the url.

Comment: Can't you use the URL parser in the language that you are using?

Comment: Is `autoplay`, if present, always preceded by `?` or `&`? If so, can `?` and `&` be added to `[^\t\n\f\r \"']`?

Comment: @Sweeper I would try that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes that's correct. Won't that cause a trailing `?` or `&` for a url like `http://www.youtube.com/embed/JFSDFS879SFD?autoplay=1` ?

Comment: Check out my answer again - you only want the first and third capture group from my pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a regex but I think you'd be better off using Go's [`"net/url"` package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url). Something like this:

```
import "net/url"

//...

u, _ := url.Parse("http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?start=10&autoplay=1")
q := u.Query()
q.Del("autoplay")
u.RawQuery = q.Encode()

clean_url_string = u.String()
```

In real life you'd want to handle errors from `u.Parse` of course.

Comment: I forgot to add that it's not just a url, but a url within  a HTML string. I have updated my question to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case you should use an HTML parser to extract the `href` attributes and then apply the above. Trying to do it all with regexes is very error prone and full of unpleasant edge cases. For example, `<a href="...?a=1&b=2">` really should appear as `<a href="...?a=1&amp;b=2">` in the HTML but you have to allow for both cases.

Comment: You are right. I guess I would have to extract both `href` and `src` attributes.

Comment: Probably `href` attributes from `<a>` tags and `src` attributes from `<iframe>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that ensures a valid page URI. Simply match this and only return capture group 1 and 3.

*Edit: The pattern is not elegant but it ensures no stale ampersands stay. The previous solution was more elegant and albeit wouldn't break anything, isn't worth the tradeoff imo.*

**Pattern**

```regex
(https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/[^?]+\?.*)(&autoplay=[01]|autoplay=[01]&?)(.*)
```

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/UOxQNE/7).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I completely rewrote it as I was unhappy.

Comment: One possible objection is that this would match `http://www.youtube.com/cats_playing_with_mice/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1`. It appears the OP is only interested in `/embed/` since that's hard-wired into his/her regex.

Comment: The OP only requested to have `autoplay=1` removed. I did not see any other constraints.

Comment: Those constraints may be implicit in the OP's regex. Dami needs to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I need the url prefix `http://www.youtube.com/embed/id` to be matched. I have updated my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @Bren It doesn't work for `http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1`

Comment: @Dami Fixed - try now.

Comment: There  are trailing `?` and `&` in a couple of test cases.

Comment: @Bren I think I'll just use your previous solution. Can you please add it to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

As the OP has linked to a regex tester that employs the the PCRE (PHP) engine I offer a PCRE-compatible solution. The one token I've used in the regular expression below that is not widely supported in other regex engines is `\K` (though it is supported by Perl, Ruby, Python's PyPI regex module, R with `Perl=TRUE` and possibly other engines.

`\K` causes the regex engine to reset the beginning of the match to the current location in the string and to discard any previously-matched characters in the match it returns (if there is one).

With one caveat you can replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
(?x)                 # assert 'extended'/'free spacing' mode
\bhttps?:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/
                     # match literal
(?=.*autoplay=[01])  # positive lookahead asserts 'autoplay='
                     # followed by '1' or '2' appears later in
                     # the string 
[a-zA-Z0-9\\_-]+     # match 1+ of the chars in the char class
[^\t\n\f\r \"']*     # match 0+ chars other than those in the
                     # char class
(?<![?&])            # negative lookbehind asserts that previous
                     # char was neither '?' nor '&'
(?:                  # begin non-capture group
  (?=\?)             # use positive lookahead to assert next char
                     # is a '?'
  (?:                # begin a non-capture group
    (?=.*autoplay=[01]&)
                     # positive lookahead asserts 'autoplay='
                     # followed by '1' or '2', then '&' appears
                     # later in the string
    \?               # match '?'
  )?                 # end non-capture group and make it optional
  \K                 # reset start of match to current location
                     # and discard all previously-matched chars
  \??                # optionally match '?'
  autoplay=[01]&?    # match 'autoplay=' followed by '1' or '2',
                     # optionally followed by '&'
|                    # or
  (?=&)              # positive lookahead asserts next char is '&'
  \K                 # reset start of match to current location
                     # and discard all previously-matched chars
  &autoplay=[01]&?   # match '&autoplay=' followed by '1' or '2',
                     # optionally followed by '&'
)                    # end non-capture group
```

The one limitation is that it fails to match all instances of `.autoplay=..` if more than one such substring appears in the string.

I wrote this expression with the `x` flag, called *extended* or *free spacing* mode, to be able to make it self-documenting.

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/iI1BRO/7)

Comment: If that pattern is to match `autoplay=1` prefixed with `?` or `&` and replace with `''` then it would break the page URI.

Comment: @Bren, I need your help. I've never been interested in such things so never learned it. (Coding is just a hobby for me, you see. I prefer it to whittling.) Could you look at my link and give me a couple examples of strings where `..autoplay=..` has been substituted out that are incorrect and tell me how they need to be changed to be correct? I'd very much appreciate that.

Comment: Sure thing! So a set of page URI query parameters is prefixed with a `?`. Certain special characters get converted to URI-friendly codes like `%20` which indicates a space for example. It's a `key=value` structure and they are delimited by ampersands. Right now your pattern would remove the question mark thus making it invalid. My current solution albeit more elegant, retains a stale, unnecessary ampersand if the autoplay is first and other parameters follow. I have a solution that addresses this non-harmful concern but isn't elegant.

Comment: So I ended up going with the not-so-elegant solution simply because it produces a better result. It's a shame I couldn't come up with a better pattern.

Comment: I think I follow. The first string at the `regexr.com` link in your answer `&autoplay=1&` in `start=10&autoplay=1&test` is matched, so when that is replaced with to an empty string you are left with `start=10test`. I just wanted to confirm that is intended. I now see that the match is `&autoplay=1` at the regex101.com link.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm actually using Golangs regex package. I have updated my link to reflect the golang engine. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland some of your test cases would fail - remember the key value pairs have to be delimited by ampersands. Also OP commented on my answer saying they are now using golang regex so that drops support for lookarounds I believe. Believe me I'm not a fan of my solution. Maybe it's just not possible with a more elegant pattern.

Comment: Dami, I'm not familiar with `Go` but I understand that it doesn't support negative lookbehinds and has other limitations compared to other engines such as PCRE. My regex will therefore not work for you. I will leave my answer, however, should a reader find aspects of it of interest.

Comment: @Bren, thanks for the help. Hopefully your solution will be helpful to Dami. I learned something from this so it was not a complete waste of time for me.